# the first axiom of countability, Hausdorff space is ......

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> If $X$ is a space satisfying the first axiom of countability, then a necessary and sufficient condition that $X$ be a Hausdorff space is that  the class of compact subsets of $X$ be a subsets of the class of closed subset of $X$.

proof: Since points are compact , it is immediate that $X$ must be at least $T_1$. Also it can be assumed that the neighborhood base $\{ V_n ‎ : n = 1,2.....\}$at each point is s.t $ V_n ‎\subseteq V_m$, $ n ‎\geq‎‎‎‎‎‎ m$. Suppose there exist $x , y$ s.t there are no disjoint pairs of neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$.Then a sequence $\{ x_n : n = 1,2....\}$may be selected by choosing each $x_n$ in the intersection  of the $n$th sets of the neighborhood bases of $x$ and $y$.The set $\{ x_n : n = 1,2....\} \cup [x]$ is compact but is not closed since $y$ is an accumulation point.

> why " a sequence $\{ x_n : n = 1,2....\}$  **may be selected by choosing each $x_n$** in the **intersection  of the $n$th sets of the neighborhood bases** of $x$ and $y$ "? what does it mean?

Comment: Let $\{B_n\}$ be the local base of $x$ and $\{V_n\}$ that of $y$. Since they cannot be separated, for each $n$, $B_n\cap V_n\neq\varnothing$ and thus we can take $x_n\in B_n\cap V_n $.

Answer (score 1):

By first-countability, fix for each $x \in X$ a countable neighbourhood base $\{ U_{x,n} : n \in \omega \}$ for $x$.  Then $U_{x,n}$ is the $n$th  set in the neighbourhood base for $x$.

If $X$ is not Hausdorff then there are distinct $x,y \in X$ such that $U \cap V \neq \varnothing$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and every neighbourhood $V$ of $y$.  In particular $U_{x,n} \cap U_{y,n} \neq \varnothing$ for all $n$.

Comment: Why  is $y$ an accumulation point?

Comment: @fatemeh: So we have taken $x_n \in U_{x,n} \cap U_{y,n}$ for each $n \in \omega$.  Note that if $V$ is any open neighbourhood of $y$ there is an $n$ such that $U_{y,n} \subseteq V$, and, in particular, $x_n \in U_{y,n} \subseteq V$.  Thus each open neighbourhood of $y$ meets $\{ x_n : n \in \omega \}$, and so $y$ is an accumulation point of that set.

Comment: Is the deffinition of accumulation point here that " a point x in topological space $X$ is accumulation point of a set $A \subset X$ if $ x \in \overline{ A - \{x \} }$ "?

Comment: @fatemeh: Sorry.  We'll work in a different order.  First, if $X$ is not Hausdorff pick distinct $x,y \in X$ which cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.  Next fix countable neighbourhood bases $\{ U_{x,n} : n \in \omega \}$, $\{ U_{y,n} : n \in \omega \}$ for $x,y$, respectively.  Note that since $X$ is T$_1$ we may without loss of generality assume that $x \notin U_{y,n}$ and $y \notin U_{x,n}$ for all $n$.  Now picking $x_n \in U_{x,n} \cap U_{y,n}$ we have that $x_n \neq y$, and so $y$ will in fact be an accumulation point of $\{ x_n : x \in \omega \}$.

Comment: Is the set $\{x_ n :n=1,2....\}∪[x]$  compact, due to $\{x_ n :n=1,2....\}$ converge to $x$? how?

Comment: @fatemeh: Perhaps not in general, but if you make the additional assumption at the second step that the countable neighbourhood base at $x$ is _descending_, then the set will be compact.